Implementing IDisposable/IDisposeAsync as an abstract base class
This question is specific to multi-threaded applications under .NET 9.
I often deal with COM Interop scenarios where references must be disposed of in a specific order, while the order of obtaining them is non-deterministic. I am also of the opinion that interface inheritence is a better approach vs implementation inheritence in scenarios that deal with programming constructs rather than business logic. This question, however, is not about approach.
I use a concrete, abstract implementation of the IDisposable pattern as the base for top-level classes that requires fine control over the order of disposal. This is the first time I am implementing the IAsyncDispose pattern and have tried to adhere to the documentation available here. Am still wrapping my head around it so not sure if the question title is appropriate.
internal abstract class Disposable:
    IDisposable,
    IAsyncDisposable
{
    private bool Disposed = false;

    private readonly List<SafeHandle?> SafeHandleList = [];
    private readonly Stack<SafeHandle?> SafeHandleStack = [];
    private readonly Queue<SafeHandle?> SafeHandleQueue = [];

    private readonly List<IDisposable?> DisposableList = [];
    private readonly Stack<IDisposable?> DisposableStack = [];
    private readonly Queue<IDisposable?> DisposableQueue = [];

    private readonly List<IAsyncDisposable?> AsyncDisposableList = [];
    private readonly Stack<IAsyncDisposable?> AsyncDisposableStack = [];
    private readonly Queue<IAsyncDisposable?> AsyncDisposableQueue = [];

    protected Disposable () { }

    ~Disposable () { this.Dispose(disposing: false); }

    public bool IsDisposed => this.Disposed;

    protected T AddDisposable<T> (T disposable) where T : IDisposable
    { this.ThrowDisposedException(); this.DisposableList.Add(disposable); return disposable; }

    protected T PushDisposable<T> (T disposable) where T : IDisposable
    { this.ThrowDisposedException(); this.DisposableStack.Push(disposable); return disposable; }

    protected T EnqueueDisposable<T> (T disposable) where T : IDisposable
    { this.ThrowDisposedException(); this.DisposableQueue.Enqueue(disposable); return disposable; }

    protected T AddAsyncDisposable<T> (T asyncDisposable) where T : IAsyncDisposable
    { this.ThrowDisposedException(); this.AsyncDisposableList.Add(asyncDisposable); if (asyncDisposable is IDisposable disposable) { this.DisposableList.Add(disposable); } return asyncDisposable; }

    protected T PushAsyncDisposable<T> (T asyncDisposable) where T : IAsyncDisposable
    { this.ThrowDisposedException(); this.AsyncDisposableStack.Push(asyncDisposable); if (asyncDisposable is IDisposable disposable) { this.DisposableStack.Push(disposable); } return asyncDisposable; }

    protected T EnqueueAsyncDisposable<T> (T asyncDisposable) where T : IAsyncDisposable
    { this.ThrowDisposedException(); this.AsyncDisposableQueue.Enqueue(asyncDisposable); if (asyncDisposable is IDisposable disposable) { this.DisposableQueue.Enqueue(disposable); } return asyncDisposable; }

    protected T AddSafeHandle<T> (T safeHandle) where T : SafeHandle
    { this.ThrowDisposedException(); this.SafeHandleList.Add(safeHandle); return safeHandle; }

    protected T PushSafeHandle<T> (T disposable) where T : SafeHandle
    { this.ThrowDisposedException(); this.SafeHandleStack.Push(disposable); return disposable; }

    protected T EnqueueSafeHandle<T> (T disposable) where T : SafeHandle
    { this.ThrowDisposedException(); this.SafeHandleQueue.Enqueue(disposable); return disposable; }

    public void ThrowDisposedException ()
    {
        if (this.Disposed)
        {
            var type = this.GetType();

            throw new ObjectDisposedException(type.FullName, $@"Attempt to access a disposed object: [{type.FullName}].");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose ()
    {
        this.Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(obj: this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.Disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Dispose objects implementing [IDisposable] and [SafeHandle].

                while (this.DisposableList.Count > 0) { try { this.DisposableList [0]?.Dispose(); } catch { } this.DisposableList.RemoveAt(0); }
                while (this.DisposableStack.Count > 0) { try { this.DisposableStack.Pop()?.Dispose(); } catch { } }
                while (this.DisposableQueue.Count > 0) { try { this.DisposableQueue.Dequeue()?.Dispose(); } catch { } }

                while (this.SafeHandleList.Count > 0) { try { this.SafeHandleList [0]?.Dispose(); } catch { } this.SafeHandleList.RemoveAt(0); }
                while (this.SafeHandleStack.Count > 0) { try { this.SafeHandleStack.Pop()?.Dispose(); } catch { } }
                while (this.SafeHandleQueue.Count > 0) { try { this.SafeHandleQueue.Dequeue()?.Dispose(); } catch { } }

                // This approach is meant to help both async and non-async consumption scenarios.
                // Any objects implementing [IAsyncDisposable] as well as [IDisposable] have already been dealt with at this point.
                // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync#implement-both-dispose-and-async-dispose-patterns.
                // It is up to the comsuming code to ensure that [DisposeAsync] is called, if needed. Example: [using (var ad = new AsyncDisposable())] vs. [await using (var ad =  = new AsyncDisposable())].
            }

            // Dispose unmanaged resources (excluding [SafeHandle] objects).
            // Free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects), override finalizer, and set large fields to null.

            this.Disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync ()
    {
        // Perform asynchronous cleanup.
        await this.DisposeAsyncCore()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Dispose of unmanaged resources.
        this.Dispose(false);

        // Suppress finalization.
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore ()
    {
        if (!this.Disposed)
        {
            while (this.AsyncDisposableList.Count > 0)
            {
                var asyncDisposable = this.AsyncDisposableList [0];

                if (asyncDisposable is not null) { try { await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); } catch { } }
                this.AsyncDisposableList.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            while (this.AsyncDisposableStack.Count > 0)
            {
                var asyncDisposable = this.AsyncDisposableStack.Pop();
                if (asyncDisposable is not null) { try { await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); } catch { } }
            }

            while (this.AsyncDisposableQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var asyncDisposable = this.AsyncDisposableQueue.Dequeue();
                if (asyncDisposable is not null) { try { await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); } catch { } }
            }

            // TODO: We want to ensure that objects implementing only [IDisposable] are handled as well.
            // Although there are not circular references between the dispose mthods, calling [this.Dispose()] here directly smells funny.
            this.Dispose();

            this.Disposed = true;
        }
    }
}

Although I have tried to adhere to best practices, I am unsure about the following:

Calling Dispose from within DisposeAsyncCore. Something about tha does not sit right with me. Perhaps I have not thought this through properly. Should I be calling the virtual implementation instead Dispose(disposing: true|false???)?
Are there any gotchas if the consuming code calls [using (var ad = new AsyncDisposable())] vs. [await using (var ad = new AsyncDisposable())]?
Am I missing anything obvious in terms of coverage? Where should the disposal of [SafeHandle] objects go? etc.
Any general comments on this implementation as a pattern are welcome.

Thye goal is to allow inherited classes to be able to add disposable objects as they please, while not having to override/burden their own Dispose(bool)/DisposeAsyncCore overrides.
Any advise would be appreciated.
Here is an example of usage for clarification:
public sealed class SampleTask:
    Disposable
{
    private readonly MemoryStream Stream1;
    private readonly Excel.Application Application;

    public SampleTask ()
    {
        // Add child objects in any desired order.
        this.Application = this.AddDisposable(new Excel.Application());
        this.Stream1 = this.PushAsyncDisposable(new MemoryStream());
    }

    // This class needs to have control over the lifetime of some
    // exposed objects irrespective of their external reference count.
    public Image GetImage () => this.AddDisposable(new Bitmap(10, 10));
    public Excel.Worksheet GetExcelWorksheet () => this.AddDisposable(this.Application.Workbooks [0].Sheets [0]);

    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing) => base.Dispose(disposing);
    protected override ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore () => base.DisposeAsyncCore();
}

EDIT: I am not sure why this question was voted closed since the comments and answers, although helpful in general, did not address the three bulleted questions (particularly the one about calling Dispose from within DisposeAsyncCore since releasing of unmanaged resources is centralized in Dispose). Irrespective of finalization, my scenario needs to assume that one of the dispose/disposeasync methods is called explicitly with using / await using statements.

In general, the only classes which should have finalizers are private types whose sole reason for existence is to manage cleanup responsibilities of a parent object; no reference to the finalizable objects themselves should escape that parent object.  Note that calling GC.SuppressFinalize on the parent object will also suppress finalization of any objects to which it holds references.  Allowing outside code to acquire references to finalizable objects makes it possible for such objects to be resurrected in wierd ways outside the control of themselves or their owners.

@supercat: I agree. Although I use the term external, the usage sample was an attempt to show how SampleTask IS, in essence, private to the application (it could be marked internal). As I mentioned in the question, this question is more about the correctness, accuracy and coverage of the implementation rather than its approach. I would love to know your thoughts on any of the bullet points though.

The fact that your class is abstract suggests that it will be used as a subtype for classes whose purposes extend far beyond the narrow scope of classes that should include finalizers.  Also, btw, I misspoke re SuppressFinalize; it won't suppress eventual finalization of derived classes, but it will serve as a KeepAlive on derived classes, which is what would typically be needed (using the actual KeepAlive function for that purpose might be be better than SuppressFinalize()).  If you want to have your class support finalizer-based cleanup, your base should hold a private reference to...

...an object to manage cleanup for you.

It's been awhile since I've code such things, but IIRC the proper technique is to have an object that encapsulates all relevant aspects of your object's state that are necessary for cleanup, as well as a small private object that can chain to a "finalizer cleanup request" method on that other object.  You should avoid either having a finalizer in your public object, nor having any strong references to your public object held by anything which has a finalizer.  Your finalizer should, however, have a "long weak reference" to your parent object, and if it triggers while that...

...WeakReference is still valid, it should reregister for finalization rather than calling Dispose.  Any code with a reference to an object can pass that reference to the WeakReference constructor and, if that object has a finalizer, or if anything with a finalizer holds a reference to it, use that WeakReference within a finalizer to resurrect the object after its finalizer has triggered, without the object having any say with regard to its resurrection.  The described technique will allow one to ensure that the finalization cleanup associated with an object can't get triggered...

...until an object is well and truly dead, with no possibility of resurrection, by using a different longer-lived object to take care of the cleanup actions without having to keep the main object in limbo.

@supercat: This should definitely be an sswer. too long for a comment.

@Charlieface: I'd already noted later that I misspoke: A call to GC.SuppressFinalize on any object will, as a side effect, behave as a call to GC.KeepAlive, and keeping any object alive will also keep alive any object which it holds a strong reference.  The effect on other referenced objects only lasts until the GC.SuppressFinalize call is executed, but it's adequate for ensuring objects don't get cleaned up while they're still in use.

Your code, like a lot of code dealing with finalization (and indeed the design of C#'s "destructors") is appears to be colored by some misunderstandings about how finalization actually works.
Contrary to popular belief, an object's Finalize method doesn't get run when an object is garbage-collected, but rather when would have been garbage-collected, but for the existence of registered finalizer somewhere.  The existence of a registered finalizer will prevent an object, or any objects to which it holds a strong reference, from actually being garbage-collected until after the finalizer has been unregistered (which would occur as a consequence of triggering it), and as long as a reference to an object exists anywhere in the universe it's impossible to be certain that code won't try to use an object agin.
If one wants to have code that will be executed when an object is actually garbage collected, one should have a public facing "shell" object which constructs and holds references to two or three private objects.  One of these should encapsulate the main object functionality and handle any subscribed events or notifications, and one of these should be a "canary" object that will sing when its owner is garbage collected.  The third object would hold just enough information to perform cleanup, but would only be required if the first object would hold references to outside objects.  The canary object should hold a "long weak reference" (a WeakReference with the optional Boolean constructor argument set to true) to its owner (the shell object), and an orinary reference to the object responsible for cleanup, and its finalize method should check if that WeakReference is still alive and reregister itself for finalization (if the WeakReference is still alive) or call the main functionality object's cleanup method.  Note that when the cleanup method is called, the main object might still be the target of things like event subscriptions, but code can be certain that no reference to the outer object will ever again exist anywhere in the universe.
It's been ages since I've done substantial coding in .NET, and many types really shouldn't need to do anything with finalization, but if finalization is needed I'd suggest using the multi-object pattern and being careful to ensure that no cycle of references would connect the canary object or cleanup object back to the shell object, and no strong references to the canary object exist outside the shell object.  When finalization does trigger, one should seek to minimize the range of objects that can't be garbage collected.

Since all comments and answers seem to focus on the Finalizer, why should I care WHEN it gets called? All the logic (order of disposal) I care about is in the two virtual dispose methods. No one has commented against the three bulleted questions. I EXPECT the methods to be triggered by using statements and that is all I care about. Is there something I am missing from from your answer/

@RaheelKhan: Because the timing of finalizer calls is unpredictable, code which uses finalizers without being designed around the way they actually work is prone to have Heisenbugs.  If e.g. one has a stream-wrapper class which is supposed to buffer data that will be written to a stream, and both that class and the stream are encalsulated using finalizable classes, .NET may call Finalize on the stream and the wrapper in either order, meaning that the file might get closed before the stream has a chance to write data to it.  While the recipe I describe above isn't complete, it...

...should hopefully help readers develop the right mindset to ensure things get cleaned up in proper sequence.  Upon further consideration, it might have been good to mention that because classes like File don't guard against premature finalization, it may be necessary for a wrapper class to ensure that a strong rooted reference to a file will be stored somewhere as long as the wrapper has pending data, but my intended point was that unless one has a sufficient understaning to make finalization work robustly, one shouldn't write classes with finalizers.


I often deal with COM Interop scenarios where references must be disposed of in a specific order.


Any general comments on this implementation as a pattern are welcome.

I have only one minute comment to make, regarding the finalizer in your Disposable class. If this class contains other finalizable objects, the order of their finalization in regard to their containing class is not guaranteed. By the time the container is up for finalization, the contained object might be already finalized. Quoting from Chris Brumme's article "Finalization":

One of the guidelines for finalization is that a Finalize method shouldn’t touch other objects. People sometimes incorrectly assume that this is because those other objects have already been collected. Yet, as I have explained, the entire reachable graph from a finalizable object is promoted.
The real reason for the guideline is to avoid touching objects that may have already been finalized. That’s because finalization is unordered.
So, like most guidelines, this one is made to be broken under certain circumstances. For instance, if your object “contains” a private object that is not itself finalizable, clearly you can refer to it from your own Finalize method without risk.

This article was written at a time when .NET 2.0 was still in the making (February 20, 2004), but contains basic principles that most likely still apply.
